# Vue.js strange data updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm Vue.js beginner and I've noticed strange behaviour in data updating.

If I execute this code, it works **properly**. Data are rendered every second :

```js
var timerVue = new Vue({
    el: "#timer",
    data: {
        object: new Date(0),
        integer: 0 
    },
});

var hours = 0;
setInterval( function(){
    timerVue.object.setHours( hours++ );
    timerVue.integer++;
}, 1000 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">
  <div>{{ object }}</div>
  <div>{{ integer }}</div>
</div>
```

But if I remove object, **data aren't updated**.

```js
var timerVue = new Vue({
    el: "#timer",
    data: {
        object: new Date(0),
    },
});

var hours = 0;
setInterval( function(){
    timerVue.object.setHours( hours++ );
}, 1000 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">
  <div>{{ object }}</div>
</div>
```

Are data need to be set in this way?:
`variable = "value"` to trigger watcher?

Thank you

Comment: Reactivity in Vue only works with plain data objects. Date is not a plain data object.

Comment: Updating `integer` and changing its value will make the instance re-render the DOM. When rendering again, it'll also re-render the `object` data. But updating `object` alone with a function, it doesn't update the object directly. This makes it non-reactive. If it were a string, it'd work.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a `computed` property: vue keep track of dependencies changes and reacts accordingly:

```
<script>
    var timerVue = new Vue({
        el: '#timer',
        data: {
            object: new Date(0),
            hours: 0
        },
        computed: {
            plain_date: function () {
                this.hours;  // just for creating a dependency
                return this.object;
            }
        }
    })


    setInterval(function () {
        timerVue.object.setHours(timerVue.hours++);
    }, 1000);

</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="timer">
  <div>{{ plain_date }}</div>
</div>
```